# Erro ao tentar executar ionic serve windows

Tags: node.js, ionic2, ionic-popup

Quando vou tentar iniciar meu projeto Ionic esta dando o seguinte erro:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'ionic:serve',
1 verbose cli   '--',
1 verbose cli   '--v2',
1 verbose cli   '--address',
1 verbose cli   '0.0.0.0',
1 verbose cli   '--port',
1 verbose cli   '8100',
1 verbose cli   '--livereload-port',
1 verbose cli   '35729' ]
2 info using npm@4.1.2
3 info using node@v7.5.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'preionic:serve', 'ionic:serve', 'postionic:serve' ]
5 info lifecycle ionic-hello-world@~preionic:serve: ionic-hello-world@
6 silly lifecycle ionic-hello-world@~preionic:serve: no script for preionic:serve, continuing
7 info lifecycle ionic-hello-world@~ionic:serve: ionic-hello-world@
8 verbose lifecycle ionic-hello-world@~ionic:serve: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle ionic-hello-world@~ionic:serve: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\xampp\htdocs\ionic\myApp\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Tecnologia\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32\wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\bin;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\Bpl;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\bin64;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\Bpl\Win64;C:\totvs\CorporeRM\API;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\cpp\bin\Intel64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\totvs\CorporeRM\API;C:\Users\Tecnologia\AppData\Roaming\npm
10 verbose lifecycle ionic-hello-world@~ionic:serve: CWD: C:\xampp\htdocs\ionic\myApp
11 silly lifecycle ionic-hello-world@~ionic:serve: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
11 silly lifecycle   'ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"' ]
12 silly lifecycle ionic-hello-world@~ionic:serve: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle ionic-hello-world@~ionic:serve: Failed to exec ionic:serve script
14 verbose stack Error: ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve: `ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:279:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:192:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:192:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:890:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid ionic-hello-world@
16 verbose cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\ionic\myApp
17 error Windows_NT 6.1.7600
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "ionic:serve" "--" "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"
19 error node v7.5.0
20 error npm  v4.1.2
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve: `ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve script 'ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ionic-hello-world package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs ionic-hello-world
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls ionic-hello-world
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

O que pode ser, já desinstalei e instalei novamente e continua dando essa mensagem.

Comment: O que você está fazendo para aparecer este erro? Está usando algum comando no terminal?

Comment: Sim, comando para startar o ionic: ionic serve

Comment: Cara, removi a tag ionic, porque o ionic2 já é está bem diferente e pode confundir as pessoas. Quanto a solução desse problema, vou tentar dar uma olhada aqui pra ti. O problema é que não consigo reproduzir isso aqui no meu pc.

Comment: @Ack Lay Ok,Obrigado

Comment: Tem algum plugin que você instalou, ou plataforma adicionada?

Comment: @Ack Lay Encontrei a solução: Ack Lay  -> npm rebuild node-sass , Obrigado !

Comment: Que legal. Mais legal seria se você explicasse o motivo, para que outras pessoas possam ser ajudadas quando chegar nessa situação. Alguém de qualquer coisa, sucesso ae! Abs;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correção:

```
 npm rebuild node-sass
```

Fonte: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1764